# Why does my Activity get destroyed on adding a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

So after editing a method in my MainAcivity, I'm getting a RuntimeException.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.timapp
    /com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Activity has been destroyed
```

I honestly have no idea where this is coming from. Searching online suggests that it's a big with the ChildFragmentManager, but doesn't give me a fix that works for me.

Any idea what I can do to fix this exception?

PS. If you need any more code or info, let me know. My mind is quite flustered by this error, so I might overlooked some stuff here.

**Full log:**

```
03-30 21:19:47.910 24785-24785/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tim.timapp, PID: 24785
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.timapp/com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
        at com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity.DrawVariableFragments(MainActivity.java:271)
        at com.example.fragments.Settings.GeneralSettingsFragment.onCreateView(GeneralSettingsFragment.java:57)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:152)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6232)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6239)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**MainActivity** (Sorry about the mess, it's a WIP):

Sorry about this, but I went over the 30.000 characters limit with the entire file.
http://pastebin.com/XZ9k995G

**DBHandler** (Was giving me grief earlier, so might have something to do with it):

```
package com.example.tim.timapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String tag = "TEST DBHandler";
    private static DBHandler sInstance;

    // Database Stuff
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LinkDatabase.db";

    // Table Stuff
    private static final String TABLE_LinkTable = "LinkTable";
    private static final String TABLE_SettingsTable = "SettingsTable";

    // LinkTable Stuff
    private static final String LT_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String LT_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String LT_COLUMN_TAG = "tag";

    // SettingsTable Stuff
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_IP = "ip";
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_PORT = "port";
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String ST_COLUMN_PASS = "pass";

    // Table Create Statements
    // LinkTable Create Statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LINKS =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LinkTable + "(" +
            LT_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            LT_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            LT_COLUMN_TAG + " TEXT" + ");";

    // SettingsTable Create Statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SETTINGS =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SettingsTable + "(" +
            ST_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ST_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            ST_COLUMN_IP + " TEXT, " +
            ST_COLUMN_PORT + " TEXT, " +
            ST_COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
            ST_COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT" + ");";

    // TODO: 28-Mar-16 DON"T FORGET TO UPDATE
    // Don't forget to update this when adding a new table.
    private static final ArrayList<String> createTablesArray = new ArrayList<String>() {{add(CREATE_TABLE_LINKS); add(CREATE_TABLE_SETTINGS);}};
    private static final ArrayList<String> tableNamesArray = new ArrayList<String>() {{add(TABLE_LinkTable); add(TABLE_SettingsTable);}};




    public ArrayList<String> tagArray;

    public static synchronized DBHandler getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            Log.d(tag, "sInstance == null");
            sInstance = new DBHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        for (String s : createTablesArray) {
            db.execSQL(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        for (String s : tableNamesArray) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + s);
        }
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> returnArray(String base, String column) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        String TABLENAME;
        if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
            TABLENAME = TABLE_LinkTable;
        } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
            TABLENAME = TABLE_SettingsTable;
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, "String Base not recognised");
            return null;
        }

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(column)) != null){
                tempArray.add(i, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(column)));
            } else {
                Log.e(tag, "String Column not recognised");
                return null;
            }
            c.moveToNext();
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
        }
        return tempArray;
    }

    // *** --------- ***
    //
    // All methods for the SETTINGS_TABLES
    //
    // *** --------- ***

    public void addSettings(String name, String ip, String port, String username, String pass) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_IP, ip);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_PORT, port);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_PASS, pass);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_SettingsTable, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void updateSettings(int id, String name, String ip, String port, String username, String pass) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_IP, ip);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_PORT, port);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(ST_COLUMN_PASS, pass);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_SettingsTable, values, "_id=" + id, null);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteSettings(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_SettingsTable + " WHERE " + ST_COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\";");
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteAllSettings() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_SettingsTable + " WHERE 1");
        db.close();
    }

    public float settingsTableSize() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        float  amount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_SettingsTable);
        db.close();
        return amount;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> settingsNameArrayMethod() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SettingsTable + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int i = 0;

        ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null) {
                nameArray.add(i, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return nameArray;
    }


    // *** --------- ***
    //
    // All methods for the LINK_TABLES
    //
    // *** --------- ***

    public void addStuffLink(String name, String tag) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LT_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(LT_COLUMN_TAG, tag);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_LinkTable, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Bundle updateStuffLink(int id, String name, String tag) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LT_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(LT_COLUMN_TAG, tag);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_LinkTable, values, "_id=" + id, null);

        db.close();
        ArrayList<String> nameArray = stuffLinksNameArrayMethod();
        ArrayList<String> tagArray = tagArrayMethod();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("nameArray", nameArray);
        bundle.putStringArrayList("tagArray", tagArray);
        return bundle;
    }

    public void deleteStuffLink(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable + " WHERE " + LT_COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\";");
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteAllStuffLinks() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable + " WHERE 1");
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> stuffLinksNameArrayMethod(){
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int i = 0;

        ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tagArray = new ArrayList<>();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null){
                nameArray.add(i, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                tagArray.add(i, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tag")));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return nameArray;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> tagArrayMethod() {
        stuffLinksNameArrayMethod();
        return tagArray;
    }

    public float stuffTableSize(){
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        float  amount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_LinkTable);
        db.close();
        return amount;
    }

}
```

**GeneralSettingsFragment**

```
package com.example.fragments.Settings;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.example.fragments.MainFragments.DialogFragments.GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog;
import com.example.fragments.MainFragments.VariableFragments.GeneralSettingsEmptyFragment;
import com.example.fragments.MainFragments.VariableFragments.GeneralSettingsVariableFragment;
import com.example.fragments.MainFragments.VariableFragments.StuffManagerVariableFragment;
import com.example.tim.timapp.DBHandler;
import com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity;
import com.example.tim.timapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GeneralSettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    DBHandler dbHandler;
    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    private static Menu optionsMenu;
    public static boolean hideDeleteAllButton = false;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettings, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainerGeneralSettings);

        if (linearLayout == null) {
            Log.e("GMF", "Layout is null");
        } else if (linearLayout.getChildCount() == 0) {
            GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog GSIID = new GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog();
            GSIID.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            hideDeleteAllButton = true;
        } else {
            hideDeleteAllButton = false;
        }
        ma.DrawVariableFragments("GeneralSettings", "draw");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.stuffmanager_actionbuttons, menu);
        optionsMenu = menu;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.removeAllButton).setVisible(!hideDeleteAllButton);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addButton:
                GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog GSIID = new GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog();
                GSIID.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                return true;
            case R.id.removeAllButton:
                dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(getActivity());
                final ArrayList<String> nameArray = dbHandler.settingsNameArrayMethod();
                final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                AlertDialog.Builder removeAllDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Delete all?")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all your devices? This is irreversible.")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black)
                        .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dbHandler.deleteAllSettings();
                                for (String name : nameArray){
                                    fm.beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentByTag(name)).commit();
                                }
                                fm.executePendingTransactions();
                                // TODO: 30-Mar-16 Add "No devices created" screen like stuffmanager
                                hideDeleteAllButton = true;
                                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                removeAllDialog.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling back into `MainActivity.DrawVariableFragments()` from within `GeneralSettingsFragment.onCreateView()` looks suspicious. Is that fragment or any others doing anything weird with the state of the activity such as calling finish() on it?

Comment: This tends to happen when your Fragments are holding on to old references to destroyed Activities. For instance, if you create your Activity, you create and attach your Fragments, then rotate the device. The Activity gets re-created, but the Fragments are saved for you, and now have the reference to the old Activity. I'd like to see what you're doing in `MainFragment`.

Comment: Please post GeneralSettingsFragment.onCreateView()

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan not as far as I'm aware. I only use it to call the `DrawVariableFragments()` method. 
@NoChinDeluxe I noticed other people saying that as well, but I'm not rotating or anything of that kind. I'll change the `MainFragment` bit to include the entire file.  
@ShadabAnsari Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();`

This isn't valid in Android. You can't create an instance of an Activity like this because it isn't actually attached to the Android processes. This instance of `MainActivity` isn't going to step through any of the lifecycle methods, which is why you're seeing the error that the activity has been stopped. It was never actually started.

Instead, remove this reference to `MainActivity`, as it's bad practice to keep references like this around in your fragment. Any time you need an instance of `MainActivity` inside a fragment, use the following example:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...

    MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    ma.DrawVariableFragments("GeneralSettings", "draw");

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Yeah I found some people mentioning the same thing online, but it had worked until now, and I couldn't come up with an alternative quickly either. I'll test this out tomorrow (current time 0:30).

Comment: I tried it, and it basically worked, but it gave me a new error. Upon fixing that error, the "Activity has been destroyed" error returned. I've updated the main question with more info.

Comment: Accepted your answer, as it did indeed fix the error I was getting. I'll be asking a new question about my new issue, since it can not be solved with this answer.

Comment: @Timmiej93 Sorry I didn't get a chance to reply to your second comment, I forgot about it! Glad to see your other question has been answered though.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, we've all got more to do then keep an eye on SO right? :)