# Why does my Activity get destroyed upon adding a fragment (#2)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, illegalstateexception

I want to make it clear that this question will look very similar to [one I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320068/why-does-my-activity-get-destroyed-on-adding-a-fragment/36320890#36320890), but that I'm not asking exactly the same thing.

In my previous question, I got a `RuntimeException`/`IllegalStateException`, which told me my Activity got destroyed upon adding a new fragment.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.timapp
    /com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Activity has been destroyed
```

In that case, it turned out it had to do with me creating new instances of `MainActivity`in an invalid way:
`MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();`
(PSA: Don't do the above, use `MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();` instead.)

I have now corrected this in my entire project, and am getting almost exactly the same error. Let me be clear: I (think I) know the original error was fixed, because I got a different error in between these two RE's, which I was able to fix myself.

To reiterate on my gibberish: Got the first RE, fixed it with the answer on my question, got a different error, fixed that myself, got *almost* exactly the same RE.

I have searched through my entire project to see if I had anything similar to the error I made before, but I can't find anything, so here I am. So basically, the answer I got on my previous question fixed my issue, temporarily. That answer however, does not help me with this new error I'm getting, that's why I'm asking this question.

**TL;DR:** Answer on Q1 fixed my issue at first(which makes it a working answer), but it does **not** fix the issue I'm having right now, which is *almost* the same.

### The actual question

So, now we've got that bit out of the way, let's get on with my issue. So, I'm getting a `RuntimeException`/`IllegalStateExcetion`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
    ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.timapp/com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity}:  
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

(PS. It's only a RE because I have my app navigate to the `GeneralSettings` fragment on startup, for debugging ease.)

I've read up on this kind of error, but nothing I could find that applies on my project.

So, what is causing this `RuntimeException`/`IllegalStateException`?

**Full log**

```
04-05 14:17:53.140 23411-23411/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-05 14:17:53.190 23411-23411/com.example.tim.timapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.tim.timapp-1/lib/x86_64
04-05 14:17:53.210 23411-23411/com.example.tim.timapp D/TEST DBHandler: sInstance == null
04-05 14:17:53.370 23411-23411/com.example.tim.timapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-05 14:17:53.370 23411-23411/com.example.tim.timapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tim.timapp, PID: 23411
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.timapp/com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
        at com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity.DrawVariableFragments(MainActivity.java:276)
        at com.example.fragments.Settings.GeneralSettingsFragment.onCreateView(GeneralSettingsFragment.java:58)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
        at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**MainActivity** (Snippet)

```
package com.example.tim.timapp;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static boolean isMainShown = false;
    private static boolean isSettingsShown = false;
    private static boolean doSavePopup = false;
    private static String backTitle = "";
    private String tag = "TEST MA";
    DBHandler dbHandler;

    Menu menu;

    public void DrawVariableFragments(String base,String token){
//        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        ArrayList<String> Data;
        dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(this);

        int AmountOfEntries;
        int SettingsContainer;
        String SettingsTag;
        Fragment SettingsVariableFragment;
        Fragment SettingsEmptyFragment;

        if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
            Data = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("StuffManager"); add("name"); add("tag"); }};
            SettingsContainer = R.id.FragmentContainer2;
            SettingsTag = getString(R.string.navdrawer_stuffmanager);
            SettingsVariableFragment = new StuffManagerVariableFragment();
            SettingsEmptyFragment = new StuffManagerEmptyFragment();
        } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
            Data = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("GeneralSettings"); add("name"); add("ip"); add("port"); add("username"); add("pass"); }};
            SettingsContainer = R.id.FragmentContainerGeneralSettings;
            SettingsTag = getString(R.string.navdrawer_generalsettings);
            SettingsVariableFragment = new GeneralSettingsVariableFragment();
            SettingsEmptyFragment = new GeneralSettingsEmptyFragment();
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, "String Base not recognised");
            return;
        }
        AmountOfEntries = dbHandler.returnArray(base, Data.get(1)).size();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsTag).getChildFragmentManager();

        if ((dbHandler.returnArray(base, Data.get(1))).size() == 0 ) {
//            Log.d(tag, "SettingsContainer1: " + String.valueOf(SettingsContainer) + ";  SettingsEmtpyFragment1: " + SettingsEmptyFragment + ";  Base1: " + base);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsEmptyFragment, (base + "EmptyFragment")).commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
            return;
        }

        if (AmountOfEntries > 0) {
            String EmptyFragName = (base + "EmptyFragment");
            if ((fm.findFragmentByTag(EmptyFragName)) != null) {
                fm.beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentByTag(EmptyFragName)).commit();
                fm.executePendingTransactions();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfEntries; i++) {
                ArrayList<String> fragmentData = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int k=1; k < Data.size(); k++) {
                    int j=k-1;
                    fragmentData.set(j, (dbHandler.returnArray(base, Data.get(k)).get(j)));
                }

                if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(SettingsContainer);
                    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                    DrawVariableFragments(base ,"draw");
                } else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                    if (fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(i)) == null) {
                        fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsVariableFragment, fragmentData.get(0)).commit();
                        fm.executePendingTransactions();
                        if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
                            ((StuffManagerVariableFragment) fm
                                    .findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(i)))
                                    .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1));
                        } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
                            ((GeneralSettingsVariableFragment) fm
                                    .findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(i)))
                                    .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1), fragmentData.get(2), fragmentData.get(3));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("draw")) {
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsVariableFragment, fragmentData.get(0)).commit();
                    fm.executePendingTransactions();
                    if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
                        ((StuffManagerVariableFragment) fm
                                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(i)))
                                .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1));
                    } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
                        ((GeneralSettingsVariableFragment) fm
                                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(i)))
                                .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1), fragmentData.get(2), fragmentData.get(3));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TEST", "WTF, nameArray.size != 0 && !> 0");
        }
    }
}
```

**GeneralSettingsFragment** (Snippet)

```
package com.example.fragments.Settings;

public class GeneralSettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    MainActivity ma;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    private static Menu optionsMenu;
    public static boolean hideDeleteAllButton = false;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettings, container, false);
        ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainerGeneralSettings);

        if (linearLayout == null) {
            Log.e("GMF", "Layout is null");
        } else if (linearLayout.getChildCount() == 0) {
            GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog GSIID = new GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog();
            GSIID.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            hideDeleteAllButton = true;
        } else {
            hideDeleteAllButton = false;
        }
        ma.DrawVariableFragments("GeneralSettings", "draw");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question should be specific, no one going to read that big question.

Comment: The minimal part of creating a [mcve] should apply for your question. Then you wouldn't hit a character limit

Comment: I can't do anything else but agree with both of you. I was probably a bit too unsure what was causing this, and wanted to be sure everything was complete. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still doing things in an unsupported way. In `MainActivity.DrawVariableFragments()` you are creating a new `GeneralSettingsVariableFragment()` and then call `getChildFragmentManager()` on it and attempt to commit a fragment.

The `GeneralSettingsFragment` has not yet been attached to an `Activity` so it does not have a host. This throws the `IllegalStateException("Activity has been destroyed")` exception you are seeing when you try to commit the `FragmentTransaction`.

It is unclear why you are creating a new `GeneralSettingsVariableFragment`when you are already inside a new instance of one.

To properly lookup an existing fragment use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(...)` or `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(...)`.

Comment: I feel terribly stupid for not realising this. Thank you mister Mulligan (once again).